# Warning when adding a column to a dataframe with the same value

Tags: python, pandas

How can I add a column to a dataframe with the same value

I've tried

```
dataframe['size']=10
```

or

```
dataframe.loc[:,'size']=10
```

but this gives

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add column to dataframe with constant value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517072/add-column-to-dataframe-with-constant-value)

Comment: You are doing it right with `dataframe['size']=10`.

Comment: @AzharKhan Then why the warning?

Comment: Is `dataframe` a ref to full dataframe or view (sub-dataframe)?

Comment: it is `dataframe=df[df['other']==something]`

Comment: `dataframe.loc[:,'size']` returns a view of dataframe. So warning there is explained at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy.

Comment: the warning also appear on `dataframe['size']=10`

Comment: I explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74487768/2847330). Your `dataframe` is a view of some dataframe.